# Create an edge parallel to the normal of a face from a given vertex

Tags: edges, normals

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this.

The way I ended up doing it, was by duplicating the face, creating a new transform from it.

But I have to do this possibly hundreds of times and I can image it getting extremely tedious.

Comment: Does the vertex belong to the face, or could it be any vertex?

Comment: No. The vertex is separate from the face.

If you extruded the face, the vertex would be caught within the extrusion, but the vertex is not aligned with the face in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the View orientation, and set an orthographic view to the face, side on, with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>.. but I still think the quickest way is with a Custom Orientation. You don't need to duplicate a face to create an orientation from it

- Right-click on the '+' in the Orientation dropdown, and add it to your Quick Menu, and/or give it a keyboard shortcut. (It used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd>)
- In the Adjust Last Operation panel, set the New Orientation op. to 'Use After Creation' and 'Overwrite Previous'
- You would *have* to select a face in any case, to avoid ambiguity, so do that...
- .. and use your shortcut, followed by vertex selection, and <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

**or**

You could try using the Cursor.

- In the Cursor tool, set its Orientation option to 'Geometry'
  and check 'Surface Project'
- Give yourself  reachable keyboard shortcuts for the Cursor tool, and the Tweak select tool
- Using the shortcuts, and with the Transform Orientation set to 'Cursor', drag the cursor over the face of interest, and <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> the vertex.